# TFS API - check in all files regardless of status

Tags: c#, tfs

I am working on a project to extend the functionality of TFS for my department.  Basically we have two repositories (Team Project Collections), a Development one and a Production one.  The development one is used by our developers and the production one is where we want to store a copy of our code.  I did a bit of research and it seemed that this was a often asked for, never delivered requests so I decided to write a bespoke app.

In my application the code does (amongst other things) the following

- Checks there are no checkouts in the development repository for the item in question
- Does a get to a directory on the client machine, without creating or relying on existing Workspace mappings
- Creates a temporary Workspace mapping on the Production repository linked to the local directory created previously
- Looks for pending changes between the local directory and the checked in code in the production
- Checks in the changes

Now it all works fine - the first time anyway, as all of the files are marked as Add and hence checked in successfully.  Subsequent times however it doesn't work as I want because it only finds the files that have been changed.  I realise this is by design, but what I want to be able to do is establish baselines of code - each baseline (changeset) containing all of the files in the project, irrespective of whether they have changed or not.  If for example there were 52 files in the project then when I click on Get This Version then I'd expect 52 files to be downloaded.

I realise that TFS is performing as designed, but I am wondering if there is anyway I can force it to do what I want.  For reference my code for checking in is as follows:

```
// create a workspace on my production server
wSpace = vcsProdServer.CreateWorkspace(cWsMapping);
wSpace.Map(pProjectName, combinedPath);
wSpace.Get();

string files = pProjectName + "/*";
int pendingAdd = wSpace.PendAdd(files, true);
int pendingEdit = wSpace.PendEdit(files, RecursionType.Full);

// get the pending changes
PendingChange[] changes = wSpace.GetPendingChanges();

// check in the changes
wSpace.CheckIn(changes, string.Format(checkinMessage, pProjectName, DateTime.Now));
```

pProjectName refers to the project in TFS ($/MyProject for example) and combinedPath is the local path where the latest version of the code is downloaded to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I think I've fixed in in case anyone is interested.  The problem was because I was deleting the wSpace at the end of each process, meaning that files that were edited or deleted weren't getting picked up.  It's not an ideal solution the way I've done it, but it appears to work.

Updated code for the workspace is:

```
// create a workspace on my production server
try
{
    wSpace = vcsProdServer.GetWorkspace(cWsMapping, vcsProdServer.AuthorizedUser);
}
catch
{
    wSpace = vcsProdServer.CreateWorkspace(cWsMapping);
    wSpace.Map(pProjectName, combinedPath);
}
wSpace.Get();
```

Now when I do a get on the label applied to the changeset I get all of the records.